# Javascript WebSockets with subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have been exploring WebSockets with Javascript, and I have the basics working, as in sending and receiving data.

However, when I check some real cases of connecting to websockets data sources, there is always this concept of `subscribing` to a channel by sending a specific JSON object.

What are the mechanics behind this, what is required on the server side to handle such subscriptions? Is the subscription a fancy way of sending and requesting data or is there more to this approach?

Comment: I was not able to find an example that uses the subscription pattern, most of the examples and tutorials for node.js websockets is using simple `on.message()` directives.

Comment: For example, when the client sends this `{
  "event": "subscribe",
  "pair": [
    "XBT/USD","XBT/EUR"
  ],
  "subscription": {
    "name": "ticker"
  }
}` what is potentially happening on the server side? From: https://www.kraken.com/features/websocket-api#message-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is a large question and I may not provide a wholeheartedly complete answer. But I'll try -

Firstly a websocket is nothing more than a standard web request without a socket *close*. Therefore the input/output on the bi-directional socket you maintain allows *pushing data*.

The two methods of sending content through a websocket are Binary and Text. Therefore when you send *a packet of data* your other end will receive a message. You'll likely receive a *finished* message depending upon your implementation or library.

As sending text is fairly cheap and the usual use-case you'll want to send a structured format - such as a the transport language JSON. your receiver (client) can simply `JSON.parse(message)` and job done.

Of course you can send any format text - such as `[my content:"my custom format"]` but that's your own implementation.

Finally a websocket connection is very basic - there is no *framework* as such to leverage. An *echo* or broadcast server is an example of *"for any incoming message, send to all connected clients"*. Publisher/Subscriber is the other general idea or 'channels' as a websockety terminology. When a user connects to your main server, they provide some credentials to authenticate and/or identify themselves as a unique entity.

**TL:DR;**

So a 'subscription' is more of a concept to allow users to connect, and assign to message streams. For many off-the-shelf libraries this is given as a freebie. This can be done through formatted transport text such as JSON.

On the server you handle the socket and build you own routine protocols. This can be as simple as a list of sockets with IDS.

---

https://Pusher.com have been a websocket service for a long time and they provide some great documentation about this very topic

https://pusher.com/docs/channels

but it's always just formatted text or a binary stream. Your server will handle any complex logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So is it all about the client sending `{“subscribe”: “updates”}` to the server and the server sends any data related to the `updates` on the backend, and if the client message is `{“subscribe”: “news”}`, then the `news` related data bits are sent? - So it is nothing more than just evaluating the client message on the server side and organising the reply accordingly?

Comment: @mbilyanov correct. The server would govern what messages are sent to whom, based upon a list of sockets you've stored against `updates` or `news`. In effect a user is _appending_ and _dropping_ from an array of applicable sockets.

Comment: I know this is a bit older but I still like to have some more insight into this: Firstly, are those subscriptions usually being processed via REST request or should you use the same websocket connection for this. I'm asking this since I it came to my ear that mixing both might be bad practise and so is using multiple websocket connections per client. So secondly, I assume one should use one connection for let's say both `updates` and `news`. I'm I correct with this?